# Replace default movement keys in Visual Studio menus

Tags: visual-studio, vsvim

I am using VsVim and I would like to make the rest of the menus in visual studio to be navigated using `j` to go down and `k` to move up.

For example, when using the `Go To All` feature, it would be nice to be able to navigate the results using `j` and `k` instead of `Down Arrow` and `Up Arrow`

Answer (score 0):

I am using autohotkey to bind alt + h/j/k/l to arrow keys.

There is script:

`LAlt & h:: Send {Left}
 LAlt & j:: Send {Down}
 LAlt & k:: Send {Up}
 LAlt & l:: Send {Right}`